# Custom Validation for Zero value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to implement the Zero or less than Zero Validation i.e User must not be able to put the value either 0 or less than that.
For this i have used following Code as follows:

```
public class PosNumberNoZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            int getal;
            if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out getal))
            {

                if (getal == 0)
                    return new ValidationResult("Value can not be Zero");

                if (getal > 0)
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;


        }
    }
```

and

```
[PosNumberNoZero(ErrorMessage = "need a positive number, bigger than 0")]
public decimal AmountReceivedByToAccount { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountReceivedByToAccount, new { style = "max-width:144%;width:132%;" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AmountReceivedByToAccount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PosNumberNoZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return (decmial)value > 0;
        }
    }
```

`object value` is your `decimal` value. If the value is **greater** than zero then it's **valid**.

Comment: My code id working nicely but when it returns as return new ValidationResult("Value can not be Zero"); then also it gets posted to the server..

Comment: That I am not getting will i have to include in View?

Comment: Should i have to include something inside the view?

Comment: @SantyEssac, How is your code _"working nicely"_? If you enter a negative number your returning `ValidationResult.Success;` The only thing you testing is if the value is equal to zero (not less than or equal to zero)

Comment: yes you are right..but when the condition is true for Zero value then also it must give me the validation error on the View and I said that My code is working nicely meaning the condition is getting true and the function return is as "return new ValidationResult("Value can not be Zero");" then also I am not getting the error on the page as said previously.

Comment: @SantyEssac - I dont really understand what you need. Your comments aren't clear enough. Do you want the validation to include zero as a valid value? If so simply change the functions content to: return (decmial)value >= 0;